# Updating a dictionary in a list in a dictionary - value change doesn't survive scope

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, scope

I have a list of dictionaries, in a dictionary. I'm trying to update the value of one of the fields. Simplified example:

```
main = {
    'list': [
        { 'value': 'hello', 'many many more': 'values' }
    ]
}

update_value = { 'value': 'test', 'many many more': 'values' }

for item in main['list']:
    if True: # just to illustrate that I need to do some check here
        item = update_value
    print(item)

for item in main['list']:
    print(item)
```

This produces the following output:

```
 {'value': 'test'}
 {'value': 'hello'}
```

When updating the dictionary in the list in this dictionary, the value change doesn't survive out of the scope. I have a vague understanding of why this is happening. I tried copying the dictionary, but that didn't work.

How can I make my changes to the `main` dictionary survive?

Using Moses Koledoye answer I've got this now, but it doesn't feel very "pretty". Is this really the "pythonic" way of doing this?

```
main = {
    'list': [
        { 'value': 'hello', 'many many more': 'values' }
    ]
}

update_value = { 'value': 'test', 'many many more': 'values' }


for index, item in enumerate(main['list']):
    if True: # just to illustrate that I need to do some check here
        main['list'][index] = update_value
        print(item)


for item in main['list']:
    print(item)
```

Comment: You won't need `enumerate` if your list contains just one dict.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye It has many of those entries actually.

Comment: And all the entries will be updated with one dict?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye No, one or more items will pass the check I illustrated with `if True` and only those should be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach only assigns the loop variable `item` to the new dict. Does not modify the existing dict.

You should assign the new value via dictionary subscription:

```
for item in main['list']:
    item['value'] = update_value['value']
```

You can equally update the entire dict via list subscription:

```
main['list'][0] = update_value.copy()
```

Assigning a copy ensures the dict in the list is thereafter independent of `update_value`, so that modifications to `update_value` are not propagated to the dict in the list.

---

The approach with `enumerate` is quite ok. However, if the keys in both dicts are matching, you can do:

```
for dct in main['list']:
    ...
    dct.update(update_value)
```

All the values are overwritten with the new ones.

Comment: Imagining I have many values in my dictionaries, is the "best" python solution this: `for index, item in enumerate(main['list']): main['list'][index] = update_value`? It seems ugly but it does work! (nb: I need to do some checks on `item` to determine if it's the one to update).

Comment: I've updated my code in the question, based on your suggested answer - maybe a bit clearer than my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are modifiying a copy of list instance but not original memory of list. So, you could try this one

```
main = {
    'list': [
        { 'value': 'hello' }
    ]
}

update_value = { 'value': 'test' }

for i in range(len(main['list'])):
    main['list'][i] = update_value
    print(main['list'][i])

for item in main['list']:
    print(item)
```